# Java equivalent to Delphi's Low() and Hi() functions for multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: java, delphi

I need an equivalent to these functions in java, but i'm not quite sure on what they do.
In my understanding of the definition, the `low()` would be `0` and the `high()` would be `.length - 1`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java arrays are always zero-based, so yes, you are right.

(Delphi (static) array might have arbitrary starting index of any ordinal type, that is why Low is useful here)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. Arrays in Java start at position 0, and you can get the last position with .length - 1.